# How to atomically replace a file?

Tags: rust, race-condition

I'm currently using:

```
if Path::new(&filename).exists() {
    remove_file(&filename)?;
    debug!("old output file deleted: {filename}");
}

let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
.create_new(true)
.append(true)
.open(&filename)?;
debug!("output file opened: {filename}");
```

I'm aware that this is a possible race condition.

How can I open and truncate a file in one operation?

Comment: Can you lock the file so when one action opens it that another action can't access it? avoids the race.

Comment: can you just overwrite file if it exists instead of removing it first?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Yes, I'd be interested in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the POSIX API, the [`creat()` system call](https://linux.die.net/man/2/creat) is a shortcut for `open()` with `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`.

In the Rust documentation for [`std::fs::OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html) we find an example for [`truncate()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.truncate).
Note also that [`std::fs::File::create()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.create) is equivalent to the `creat()` system-call.

Opening a file this way will create it if it does not already exist, or truncate it if it already exists; all the subsequent write calls will take place in a file which is originally empty.